# Play animation before Unmount

Tags: reactjs, animation, transition, react-transition-group

I have a react app and I'm using the `<Transition>` component from the `react-transition-group` package to create transition animations when the component is created and destroyed. I set the **in prop** in the `componentWillMount` cycle. However, I can't seem to figure out how to revert the **in prop** back when the Component is about to be destroyed. The docs didn't really say much about the exit transition

Here is my code:

```
const defaultStyle = {
    transition: `opacity 1000ms ease-in-out`,
    opacity: 0,
    padding: 20,
    display: 'inline-block',
    backgroundColor: '#8787d8'
};

const transitionStyles = {
    entering: { opacity: 0 },
    entered: { opacity: 1 },
    exiting: { opacity: 1 },
    exited: { opacity: 0 },
};

export default class Home extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            in: false
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const home = this;

        // This: Works Perfectly
        home.setState({ in: true });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        const home = this;

        // This: Not so much
        home.setState({ in: false });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Transition in={ this.state.in } timeout={ 0 }>
                {(state) => (
                    <div className="page" style={{
                        ...defaultStyle,
                        ...transitionStyles[state]
                    }}>
                        I'm A fade Transition!
                    </div>
                )}
            </Transition>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html#componentwillleave

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm using react-transition-group v2

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that your component is ever actually unmounting and that `componentWillUmount()` is getting invoked? The v2 docs seem to suggest that components stay in the DOM even after reaching the `exited` transition state. They expose an `unmountOnExit` `prop` that should force the component to unmount after it reaches the exited state. Per the docs:

> By default the child component stays mounted after it reaches the 'exited' state. Set unmountOnExit if you'd prefer to unmount the component after it finishes exiting.

Comment: I don't want to unmount onExit, I want to exit onUnmount. I'm using a router to switch components. I want to activate the exit state just before the component is unmounted and then continue unmounting after the animation is completed.